# How do I solve "RouteNotFoundException: Route "jsonapi.settings" does not exist" which occurs while installing the REST UI module?

Tags: 8

When I am trying to install or uninstall a module the below error shows up.

The same error is displayed when I go to webservices (Home > Admin > Configuration > Web Services).

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "jsonapi.settings" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 208 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getRoute('jsonapi.settings') (Line: 271)
Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('jsonapi.settings', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 105)
Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->generateFromRoute('jsonapi.settings', Array, Array, 1) (Line: 762)
Drupal\Core\Url->toString(1) (Line: 182)
Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator->generate('JSON:API', Object) (Line: 64)
Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator->generateFromLink(Object) (Line: 138)
Drupal\Core\Link->toString() (Line: 30)
template_preprocess_admin_block_content(Array, 'admin_block_content', Array) (Line: 287)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('admin_block_content', Array) (Line: 431)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, ) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 227)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 117)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array, Object, Object) (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object, 'kernel.view', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view', Object) (Line: 156)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Can someone please help?
Please let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Can you provide us the precise Drupal version? Please also be aware the Drupal 8 is end-of-life software. In addition can you confirm that the JSON:API module is installed on the site?

Comment: Hi @cilefen, 
Thanks for the quick reply! 

The current version is 8.9.13
JSON:API module is installed - Yes

Comment: For JSON:API you need to install this module https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras

Comment: Hi @4uk4, I have JSON API Defaults, JSON:API, JSON:API Extras and Serialization modules installed.

Comment: 'jsonapi.settings' is a well-known route defined by the JSON:API module so it seems like JSON:API isn't quite installed, or, there is a platform issue.

Comment: Hi @cilefen, I believe, JSON API is part of core (Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi). How to uninstall it, as it is required by other JSON API modules?

Comment: I vote to close the question, it's unclear how JSON:API and REST UI are connected. They are just two random modules.

Comment: @4uk4, I agree, REST UI and JSON API are different modules. But I have also mentioned I get the error when I try to access webservices. Just trying to give more information where I am receiving the errors so, that community could provide the solution quicker.

Comment: What's going on here is that you have a menu block which at one time added a link to the route named 'jsonapi.settings', which as I already know is provided by the core module JSON:API. At this time, the 'jsonapi.settings' route no longer exists. This suggests JSON:API module is not installed, or is missing, or that some PHP platform issue exists. I do not know anything else to say about this one.

Comment: @cilefen, Thanks for the support! Any suggestions on how to debug this issue? What needs to be checked to find any leads?(on JSON:API or PHP platform)